# R: Calculating MSE

Tags: r, regression, mse

I've got a function, I've added noise to it, then smoothed it to get a regression line. How can I find the MSE between the original function and the regression line at 30 equally spaced points?

Or, how can I give R an x value and get the y value on a regression line?

This is a scaled down version of my problem:

```
> test<- function(m) {3*m^2+7*m+2}  
> r=rnorm(10)  
> m=1:10/10  
> plot(test(m)+r)  
> lines(smooth.spline(1:10,test(m)+r),col="red")
```

So I've got the true function values at the 10 equally spaced points i.e. test(m). I just need a way to extract the smooth.spline values at those 10 points, then I should be able to calculate MSE.

Comment: Could you show a reproducible example- that is, show your data (or a subset of it) using `dput`, then show the code you used to smooth it? That would make it much easier to answer in a way that's helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
y <- test(m)+r
y.pred <- predict(smooth.spline(1:10,y))$y
mean((y-y.pred)^2)        ## variance (could mult by n/(n-r) for an unbiased estimate)
mean((test(m)-y.pred)^2)  ## MSE
```

Comment: Guessing you meant "mult by `n/(n-length(r))`" or some such (although at the moment that would be nonsense so what did you mean)?

Comment: I just meant `r` as some measure of effective df of the model (a little hard to figure out for a smoothing spine anyway).  I just forgot we'd already used that symbol.

Comment: Using `$df` to access a 'smooth.spline'-classed object is possible. Since I suspect you knew that, I'm wondering what your objections to its use might be?

Comment: no, I didn't know that.  What can i say, I was in a hurry (feel free to edit my answer ...)